# Hibernate Update query exception

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Hi I am writing the hql update query but I am getting exception as follow.And my query is like this.Could anyone please identify what would be mistake here.

**Query**

```
 Query Updatepriamray = s.createQuery("update EmployeeDeparment set primarydept=:primedep,status=:status where employeeentity.employeeid=:empid and primarydept=:dep");
                                        Updatepriamray.setBoolean("primedep", false);
                                        Updatepriamray.setBoolean("status", false);
                                        Updatepriamray.setInteger("empid", deparment.getEmployeeentity().getEmployeeid());
                                        Updatepriamray.setBoolean("dep", true);
                                        Updatepriamray.executeUpdate();
```

**Exception**

Full stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute update query
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:259)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1141)
        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:94)
        at com.treamis.hr.employee.HRCalss.EmployessEdit(HRCalss.java:406)
        at com.treamis.hr.employee.EditEmployeeSave.execute(EditEmployeeSave.java:32)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
        at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
        at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
        at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.treamis.academics.examlist.SessionFilterServelet.doFilter(SessionFilterServelet.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1770)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2345)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2330)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:75)
```

Comment: Is your server up? I remember forgetting countless times to set up xampp/wampp/whatever. Also could you show line 103? or is it the query?

Comment: I think this will help you. Check this [link][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766785/fixing-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-for-a-stuck-my

Comment: i have update my full stack trace please look at above.

Comment: You have lost connection to db it seems.

Comment: It seems that your application cant reach the server. Can you perform other queries? Try insert, remove or select and see if it lets you

Comment: all queries are working fine except update query.

Comment: It may be stupid but try to leave a blank space between the = and the :  Eg: primarydept = :primedep instead of primarydept=:primedep. Also check the type of the fields in the database, make sure they are indeed integers or booleans.

Comment: Also you can try to use the setParameter(int position, Object val) instead of setBoolean or setInteger, or setParameter(int position, Object val, Type type).