# Database locked error using insert into CI

Tags: php, sqlite, codeigniter

I am trying to insert into my database, however it is not working. This is the error I get:

```
Error Number: HY000/5
database is locked
```

This is my code:

```
$this->load->database();
$data = array('x' => '1','alfa' => '1', 'afstand' => '1', 'laatst' => '1');

if($this->db->insert('configuratie', $data))                
{
    echo "success";
}
else{
    echo "error";
}
```

I am using a SQLITE database.
What's going wrong or what could I try?

Comment: Please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000336/how-to-debug-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766785/fixing-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-for-a-stuck-my
90% problem related with timeout.

Comment: So how do I fix it in php?

Comment: I think problem is with access to file (maybe file is readonly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted my database file and restored it from a backup and then it worked again.