# Why am I getting a "Lock wait timeout exceeded" error while trying to update a MySQL entry?

Tags: mysql

I have a database that I am trying to update a row value in but I am getting a "lock wait timeout" error. This is what the table looks like:

```
mysql> use rti;
Database changed
mysql> explain resin_products;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| resin_product_id   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| manufacturer       | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name               | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| model_number       | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| resin_type         | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| primary_type       | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| group              | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| teir               | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| chemical_structure | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| physical_structure | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| color              | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| total_capacity     | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| salt_split_CAP     | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price_per_cuft     | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| comments           | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Here is the command:

```
mysql> UPDATE resin_products SET price_per_cuft='00.04' WHERE resin_product_id=1;
```

This is the error that occurs after about 30 seconds:

```
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

This is what my "lock_wait" variable is set to:

```
mysql> show variables like 'lock_wait_timeout';
+-------------------+----------+
| Variable_name     | Value    |
+-------------------+----------+
| lock_wait_timeout | 31536000 |
+-------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Possible dublicate of [Getting “Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction” even though I'm not using a transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5836623/4275342)

Comment: or [Fixing “Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction” for a 'stuck" Mysql table?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2766785/4275342)

Comment: look the result from  > SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First see the list of locked tables:

```
show open tables where in_use>0;
```

Also you can see the thread which is using this table:

```
show full processlist;
```

And then you can kill that thread

```
kill 141;
```

Comment: I am not getting any open tables issue. This is what I am getting: mysql> show open tables where in_use>0;
Empty set (0.00 sec)    I will try and run the command that produces the error again and then immediately follow it with show open tables where in_use>0;

Comment: You can see more status by the command: `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`

Comment: It turned out to be a process that was running for too long. I ran `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` and then killed all of them. That solved the issue.