# delete operation failed Error code 1205 in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table having 5 million data on production server. my database is mysql.
when I fire delete query, I faced below error

> Error code 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded, try restarting transaction

I want to delete the data.

Comment: You want to delete all ? if yes a better way is `truncate table_name`

Comment: Look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766785/fixing-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-for-a-stuck-my. Maybe it'll help.

Comment: Run query "CHECK TABLE table_name EXTENDED;", In my opinion this table damaged.